# Zeros of partition function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a polynomial in z of degree N and it can be factorised as
$$Z_N(z)= \sum_{n=0}^N g(n, N)z^n = k  \prod_{n=0}^N (1- \frac z z_n),  $$
 The quantities $z_n$ are the N zeros of the partition
function $Z_N(z), z=e^{-\beta  \varepsilon}$, $k$, $\varepsilon$ are the constants. All the g(n,N) are positive, no zero of $Z_N(z)$ can be real and positive: that is, the zeros $z_n$ will generally lie in the complex plane away from positive real axis. Suppose we have also the asymptotic behavior for $g(n,N)$ under $N \longrightarrow\infty$. I would like  to investigate the zeros of this partition function *qualitatively* in the limit $N \longrightarrow\infty$, to clear up dependence  on qualitative behavior of $g(n, N)$   the location and density of zeros. Maybe there is some pedagogical introductory to the subject?

EDIT. In particular I would like to consider the following simple example:
$$Z_N(z)= \sum_{n=0}^N g(n, N)z^n , $$
 where  $g(n, N)=e^{(n-\rho n^2/N)}$, $\rho=const$ as $N\longrightarrow\infty$